# Переадресcация с поддоменов с www на без www

Tags: php, .htaccess, php7

Добрый день:)

Скажите, пожалуйста, как указать переадресацию с

`http://www.domen1.test.ru/index.php`

на

```
http://domen1.test.ru
```

Сейчас указал в `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но это работает только на без index.php, с ним не переадрессует. Надо, чтобы переадресация работала с index.php и без него.

Т.е., если обратятся по адресу `http://www.domen1.test.ru/index.php` 
перекинуло на `http://domen1.test.ru`, а если обратятся по адресу `http://www.domen1.test.ru` перекинуло на `http://domen1.test.ru`

Поддоменов очень много всяких разных.

Comment: А к конфигам сервера доступ есть? И что за веб-сервер?

Comment: Я в корне сайта создал .htaccess и написал то, что указал выше (3 строчки) и все работает отлично для поддоменов без index.php. А надо, чтобы еще с поддоменов с index.php переадресовывало на без index.php

Comment: Что за хостинг? VPS или простой веб-хостинг?

Comment: Простой веб-хостинг. Размещен простой сайт.

Comment: @demol0cv Я так понял, нужно к моему коду добавить не обязательный параметр `index.php`, т.е. он может быть, а может и не быть. Вот как его добавить в правила, я не знаю(

Comment: @demol0cv Может быть так еще добавить 2 строчки дополнительно? - `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)/index\.php$` и
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`